# Docker + Jenkins + AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, docker

I am planning to achieve Continuous Integration using Jenkins. But this CI has to be achieved inside a docker container. 
Tools used are

- Docker
- Jenkins
- GIT
- Maven
- AWS

I'm planning to build a docker container with a Jenkins image. My doubt is how to install GIT and Maven inside a Docker Container and access them to build a job with Maven from a GIT repository?

Later, how to deploy it to my AWS instance?

Comment: There are lots of guides on this, such as: https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/putting-jenkins-docker-container

Answer (score 3):

You can Create a DockerFile and Mention whatever you want to Download, Install and the Commands you want to run in the **DOCKERFILE**.

Refer Docker Documentation for the same.
You can even add the resources from your local to your docker container.
The image will be ready once you will build the docker file.

So to Install Git And Maven inside the Docker Container.
You need to include the sourcelinks and installation commands of the resources.

Below I have mentioned a sample docker file to install JDK and Tomcat.

To install Git and Maven in it, You need to add following lines.

GIT:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install git
```

Maven:

```
RUN wget http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/maven/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.1-bin.tar.gz

ENV (your Path)
```

and build commands, etc...

Once you are done with it.
you can anyway continue the commands using Jenkins console. Make sure you install the right plugins.
You can figure it out easily.

You can also achieve Continuous Integration by 
Installing only the JDK and Tomcat on top of the docker.
and 
Implementing the remaining maven build and jenkins part outside the container and place it in the docker via jenkins.
This way helps you to create and keep a copy of the docker image in any docker repository as you go on including changes to the environment.

But Choses it according to the scenario.

Hope it Helps.. :)

---

> 

### Sample Docker File:::

---

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Sarat <sarat.e99@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends wget pwgen ca-certificates && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION 8
ENV TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION 8.0.11
ENV CATALINA_HOME /tomcat

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y git build-essential curl wget software-properties-common zip unzip

# Install JDK 8
RUN \
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer wget unzip tar && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer

# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

# INSTALL TOMCAT
RUN wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION}/v${TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    wget -qO- https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION}/v${TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION}.tar.gz.md5 | md5sum -c - && \
    tar zxf apache-tomcat-*.tar.gz && \
    rm apache-tomcat-*.tar.gz && \
    mv apache-tomcat* tomcat

ADD user.sh /user.sh
ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /*.sh

#EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to make Jenkins build NodeJS, Ruby, and Maven on Docker**

This was a problem I faced and I thought I'd try to solve it robustly. Jenkins is great but when you want to move it to another system you realize how much baggage you created by installing one service after the other that it relies on. To decouple this Docker is a great choice but the barebones one that Jenkins makes is just that, very barebones.

[Dockerfile](https://github.com/QuantumMob/jenkins/blob/master/Dockerfile)

[My article](https://blog.qmo.io/how-to-make-jenkins-build-nodejs-ruby-and-maven-on-docker/) explaining the dockerfile as well as how to use or extend it

**How to run Docker on AWS**

I feel like this is a very obvious question and there are probably loads of solutions that come to mind.

- Install docker directly onto your EC2 instance using the [standard example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_one/#/docker-for-linux) from Docker.
- Use [AWS EC2 Container Service](https://aws.amazon.com/docker/). They created a whole service to make running Docker on AWS easier.